# Param is missing or the value is empty: reservation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OK - it will take a while to explain the issue, bear with me:

I'm currently following a tutorial on how to develop AIRBNB. As part of the reservation model it has start_date/end_date and these two were used within the reservations controller private actions.

```
 private
        def reservation_params
          params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date)
        end
```

The tutorial then explains how to create a form under reservation view which then will be used on the room page.

**reservations/_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for([@room, @room.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>Check In</label>
              <%= f.text_field :start_date, readonly: true, placeholder: "Start Date", class: "form-control datepicker" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>Check Out</label>
              <%= f.text_field :end_date, readonly: true, placeholder: "End Date", class: "form-control datepicker", disabled: true %>
            </div>
          </div>
    :
    :
    :

     <%= f.submit "Book Now", id: "btn_book", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block", disabled: true %>
        <% end %>
```

I'm trying to adapt the course to my purposes. I don't need the start/end date. All I need users to do is to click the button BUY in order to complete the purchase (price and quantities are fixed). So here is what I though I would do (obviously no success for now)

ReservationsController:

```
private
        def reservation_params
          params.require(:reservation)
        end
```

**reservations/_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for([@room, @room.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
     <%= f.submit "Book Now", id: "btn_book", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block", disabled: true %>
 <% end %>
```

The result of this is : PARAM IS MISSING OR THE VALUE IS EMPTY:RESERVATION

QUESTION: How should use the params. in the private statement without .permit part? What do I do wrong overall?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `binding.pry` to debug your program, Examine the incoming `params` array and figure out where your params are, then figure out why they aren't where you thought they would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should use the params. in the private statement without .permit part?

If you don't submit any params, you don't need `reservation_params`, which require the `params` to contain non-empty `reservation` (it means, a key `reservation`, with a non-empty value).

On submit, you can just create a `reservation` in the controller method (I assume, the `create` one):

```
def create
  @room.reservation.create!
  ...
end
```

For now, I guess, the method has something like `@room.reservation.new(reservation_params)`, which is not useful since `reservation_params` are empty.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! Thank you so much.. I removed private params and restructure the create action to @reservation = current_user.reservations.build.